# Using selenium python - After I click a button a new URL is opened in the same tab, but then selenium cannot find any elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
#open new url
carestarted = driver3.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="ApplyForm"]/input[28]')
driver3.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", carestarted)
#switch to new url
time.sleep(10)
currenturl = driver3.current_url
driver3.get(currenturl)
#care credit last 4 new url
carelast4 = driver3.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pfLandinglast4"]')
driver3.execute_script("arguments[0].send_keys(ssn3);", carelast4)
```

after I switch to new URL, selenium does not seem to be able to find anything. It just keeps running with no errors, until I stop code then it returns errors. But the errors are all over the code some are on line 70 some on line 700 so I doubt they are connected somehow.

I have tried using `window_handles` I've tried not switching to a new URL and instead leaving it to do nothing after new URL is opened so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Basically, in your code you're reloading the page. Try adding sleep after reloading the page. Also, check if the xpath is changed after reloading the page.

Comment: Have you checked that the new url does not have the element you are searching inside an iframe?. If it is the case you have to switch to that iframe before searching for something.